# Javascript logic for finding out whether a link is internal

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, history.js

I'm having some issues with the following function inside of https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

For a url that is in the following form:

```
http://rooturl.com/?alfa=a
```

or any other query string is not being recognized as internal link. (Where rooturl.com is my internal homepage)

```
    // Internal Helper
    $.expr[':'].internal = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
        // Prepare
        var
            $this = $(obj),
            url = $this.attr('href')||'',
            isInternalLink;

        // Check link
        isInternalLink = url.substring(0,rootUrl.length) === rootUrl || url.indexOf(':') === -1;

        // Ignore or Keep
        return isInternalLink;
    };
```

How can I modify this function to make it count internal URLs with query strings as 'internal links'??

for reference that function is used in the following context:

```
$this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy, .no-ajaxy a)').click(function(event){
     // so on...
});
```

Comment: simple: parse the url, pull out the domain, check that it's an acceptable one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is check for the ? in the URL as it is required for query strings

```
isInternalLink = url.substring(0,rootUrl.length) === rootUrl || url.indexOf('?') !== -1 || url.indexOf(':') === -1;
```

But another URL might have query string and be external so you might need to use split() and check that the first bit matches the rootUrl

```
var bits = url.split('?');

if (bits[0] === rootUrl) isInternalLink = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
$('a[href^=http]')
```

will only return links with external hrefs

or do something like this

```
$('a').filter('[href^=http]')
```

or

```
$(this).is('[href^=http]')   //will return true if external hrefs
```

in your case